# Spotfire: moving avg calculation for single column , grouped by an different values of another column

Tags: spotfire

I need help in getting moving average values grouped by specific column. The default moving avg value calculates based on the interval and wont group by any other column. Hence I tried using something like below:

Avg (Column C ) over (LastPeriods(6,Column B)), this gives continuous avg , but wont group on the another column . I need moving avg separately for different set of values grouped by a specified column.

I tried something like (Avg (Column C ) over (LastPeriods(6,Column B), column A)). But this is not correct.

Any help appreciated.

Below is the sample data .
[image]

I need moving Avg Grouping Column A ie for 170319 the moving avg should be calculated separately and for 170318 separately and 170320 etc...... Remaining columns like Column D and E will have some values which is not required

Comment: @NischeyAnand- Could you post some sample data?

Comment: @ksp585   I have added the sample data

Comment: @NischeyAnand- What were you trying to calculate with this expression (LastPeriods(6,Column B)? what is the date range that you are looking for?

Comment: MOVING AVG BASED ON THE 6 POINTS INTERVAL OF LAST PERIODS

Comment: @NischeyAnand- Can you include columns with Spotfire output and correct output in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't clarify if you want the last 6 days, 6 rows, or what ever but here are some options:

**Moving average, sorted on the time, grouped by Column A**

```
Avg([Column B]) over (Intersect([Column A],AllPrevious([Column B])))
```

**Moving average over the previous 6 rows (based on Column B ascending)**

Insert calculated column and name it GroupedRowID. This applies a row number based on the grouping of Column A, sorted on Column B ascending.

```
Rank([Column B],"asc",[Column A])` as[GroupedRowID]
```

Then use this for the moving average

```
Avg([Column B]) over (Intersect([Column A],LastPeriods(6,[GroupedRowID])))
```

This should get you going...

Comment: @ scsimon      Thanks .. Second part helped me achieving my requirement.

Comment: Awesome @NischeyAnand  glad to help